# angularJs - How to prevent extra code from being executed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have a complex Edit form which has, in particular, this code:

```html
<uib-tab ng-show="currentItDraftHeader.treeType===2">
    <uib-tab-heading>
        <i class="fa fa-picture-o"
            uib-tooltip="@Labels.images"
            tooltip-placement="bottom">
        </i>
    </uib-tab-heading>
    @Html.Partial("ImageSelector")
</uib-tab>
```

When the form is loading, there is an error that prevents creation of currentItDraftHeader. Yet the ImageSelector form is being invoked and the code from its controller gets executed as well. How can I prevent this from happening? I have another problem - I have LoadView method which has several functions each of them calls service to get the data. I want to stop the execution of the code as soon as the first request failed, but since they all are asynchronous, I think they all are executed. What is the best way to prevent calling unnecessary code after the very first error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-show` determines if an element is visible or not but the `DOM` is created anyways, therefore `ImageSelector` is invoked,

[ng-show](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-show.asp)

you should use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`

`ng-if` determines whether the element is created or not, if the condition is `false` then the `DOM` won't be created and `ImageSelector` son't be invoked.

[ng-if](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-if.asp)

so, try this 
`<uib-tab ng-if="currentItDraftHeader.treeType===2">`

for the second problem, you have to wait for the first request to check if it fails or not then proceed to the other, take a look at [promises](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) to see how to handle that.

[async / await](http://debuggerdotbreak.judahgabriel.com/2017/04/24/making-typescript-asyncawait-play-nice-with-angularjs-1-x/)  is a good alternative if you don't want `promises`

Comment: I was thinking of trying ng-if. I'm going to try it as soon as I figure out my toastr problems :(